# How to access local files of the filesystem in the Android emulator?

Tags: android

I want to know whether there is a method to access local files (say text files, web pages) of the filesystem in Android emulator.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 for Android development.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to access those local files in your application running on android emulator...

Comment: No.. I want to access local files in my OS say (/home/ubuntu/myfile.txt) from emulator\

Comment: `C:\Users\{Acount}\Documents\AndroidStudio\DeviceExplorer\emulator-5554\sdcard\Android\data\..\file.ext` in my case

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use the `adb` command which comes in the tools dir of the SDK:

```
adb shell
```

It will give you a command line prompt where you can browse and access the filesystem. Or you can extract the files you want:

```
adb pull /sdcard/the_file_you_want.txt
```

Also, if you use eclipse with the ADT, there's a view to browse the file system (*Window->Show View->Other*... and choose *Android->File Explorer*)

Comment: Recommended use to get sdcard path:
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = sd.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: The GUI view is ultimately a function of DDMS, and so while it can be launched from within Eclipse, it can also be used by running DDMS without Eclipse.  (Though personally I always use the command line adb tools).

Comment: On a recent install the exe location is "path\to\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe"

Comment: This solution worked for me after launching the emulator from the command line whereas the Android Studio solution did not.

Comment: 'adb' is not recognized once I'm inside the shell, and if I try to navigate to the file, I get 'Permission denied'. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is where to find the adb command: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/94049/65728

Answer (score 106):

In Android Studio 3.0 and later do this:

View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer

Comment: Is it possible to rename a file or folder with the Device File Explorer? I cannot find this feature.

Comment: and how to save changes of a file?

Comment: I found it on 
View > Tool Windows > Device Explorer

Answer (score 49):

In addition to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847670/878954), if you are using Android Studio you can

1. invoke `Android Device Monitor`,
2. select the device in the `Devices` tab on the left,
3. select `File Explorer` tab on the right,
4. navigate to the file you want, and
5. click the `Pull a file from the device` button to save it to your local file system

Taken from [Working with an emulator or device's file system](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#emulator)

Comment: file explorer is empty

Comment: To open `Android Device Monitor`, double press Shift (in Android Studio) and type in `"Android Device Monitor"`.

Comment: Is it possible to rename a file or folder with the Android Device Monitor?

Comment: **Android Device Monitor deprecated**.
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor
"Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2. The features that you could use through the Android Device Monitor have been replaced by new features. The table below helps you decide which features you should use instead of these deprecated and removed features."

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio 3.5.3, the Device File Explorer can be found in View -> Tool Windows.

It can also be opened using the vertical tabs on the right-hand side of the main window.

Answer (score 1):

Update! 
You can access the Android filesystem via Android Device Monitor. In Android Studio go to  Tools >> Android >> Android Device Monitor.

Note that you can run your app in the simulator while using the Android Device Monitor. But you cannot debug you app while using the Android Device Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

To open the Device Explorer, select View > Tool Windows > Device Explorer or click the Device Explorer button in the tool window bar.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

Select a device from the drop-down list.

Interact with the device content in the file explorer window:
Right-click a file or directory to create a new file or directory.
Save, upload, delete, or synchronize the selected file or directory to your machine.

Double-click a file to open it in Android Studio.