# Is there a way to browse/view the sd storage on a android virtual device using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am just learning about data file operations in the Android OS, and would like to be able to browse and even edit/delete files in the avd sd storage card.  I have found a `sdcard.img` file in the windows file system (path something like: `C:\Users\myloginname\.android\avd\AVD_v10.avd)`, but I don't know how or really want to mess with it especially if there is a graphical method.

Haven't found much in internet search, even search term suggestions might be helpful.  I did find a stackoverflow question about how to do this in eclipse using DDMS, the *Tools > Android > Monitor* (DDMS Included) option in my android studio doesn't find a JRE, so if that is what I need, I will just need to better install/configure that Java.

Comment: In addition to the command-line method at the linked question, you can use the ddms tool independent of eclipse, but it will probably require a properly configured JRE.

Answer (score 0):

[this linked so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847654/how-to-access-local-files-of-filesystem-in-android-emulator) describes a way to access/browse files on the running avd using a `adb shell` command session. that is really good enough although not gui